# What is the default MessageFactory for Log4J

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

The documentation for `org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger` says

```
   /**
     * Logs a message with parameters at the given level.
     *
     * @param level the logging level
     * @param message the message to log; the format depends on the message factory.
     * @param params parameters to the message.
     * @see #getMessageFactory()
     */
    void log(Level level, String message, Object... params);
```

But:

1. Which MessageFactory is used when I didn't set any?
2. Which message format uses the default factory?
3. How can I set my own factory in case the default factory can't do what I need?

**Update:**

Please add class names and XML element names to the answer. It is very difficult to find anything about Log4J 2.x on Google without the proper search terms.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. If you don't set a message factory, `ParameterizedMessageFactory` is used by default.
2. By default, log4j uses a message factory for parameterized messages, so you can do `logger.warn("hello {}", user.getName());`
3. You set your own factory by calling `LogManager.getLogger(name, messageFactory)` when you obtain a logger.

If you want the String.format kind of params (the System.out.printf format) you would use `LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class, new StringFormatterMessageFactory())` to obtain a logger.

If your most common usage is parameterized messages (the {} format), but if you occasionally want more control over the output format as afforded by the string formatter, you can declare your logger normally (so it uses {} parameterized messages), and use the `Logger.printf` methods.

Example:

```
class MyClass {
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class);

    public void someMethod() {
        // use printf here to precisely control the number of digits displayed
        logger.printf(Level.INFO, "pi: %.5f", Math.PI);
    }
}
```

This is all in code. Configuration (XML or otherwise) is not involved.

Comment: I take it then that the class of default MessageFactory is not officialy defined. And an answer (i.E. which XML Element) to point 3 would have been nice. If you know the name it make Google so much easier.

Comment: I was away from my PC and answered on my iPhone, so sorry for the inexact answer. I think it had all the information you asked for (including point 3) but I will add the classnames now. The configuration (XML or otherwise) does not come into play here.

Comment: Thanks. No XML — that explains why I did not find anything. But printf will do the trick for me. All my problems solved.

Answer (score 5):

This thread is already about one year old, but maybe I can still help some guys, because I just had the same problem and found out a way how to set your own default MessageFactory. It's a bit tricky, maybe someone else knows a better way without creating so much classes. But for me it works:

1. Create your own MessageFactory (extend from `AbstractMessageFactory` or just use the `MessageFactory` interface)
2. Create a new LoggerContext (extend from the `LoggerContext` class or use the `LoggerContext` interface

   - Override `newInstance(LoggerContext, String, MessageFactory)` and return your previously defined MessageFactory if argument `messageFactory` is `null`
3. Create a new ContextSelector (extend from `ClassLoaderContextSelector` or just use the `ContextSelector` interface).

   - Override the method createContext(String, URI) and return a new instance of your previously defined LoggerContext
4. Create a file `log4j.component.properties` in your classpath and set the property `Log4jContextSelector` to the fully-qualified-name of your in step 3 created contextSelector

   - Alternative: Don't create the file, just set the system property `Log4jContextSelector` to the fqn

Some code examples (without any comments):

**MessageFactory:**

```java
public final class OwnMessageFactory extends AbstractMessageFactory
{
  public static final OwnMessageFactory INSTANCE = new OwnMessageFactory();

  @Override
  public Message newMessage(final String message, final Object... params)
  {
    return new OwnDataMessage(message, params);
  }
}
```

**LoggerContext:**

```java
public class OwnLoggerContext extends LoggerContext
{
  // constructors

  protected Logger newInstance(final LoggerContext ctx, final String name, MessageFactory messageFactory)
  {
    if (null == messageFactory)
      messageFactory = OwnMessageFactory.INSTANCE;

    return super.newInstance(ctx, name, messageFactory);
  }

}
```

**ContextSelector**:

```java
public class OwnContextSelector extends ClassLoaderContextSelector
{

  @Override
  protected LoggerContext createContext(String name, URI configLocation)
  {
    return new OwnLoggerContext(name, null, configLocation);
  }

}
```

**log4j2.component.properties**:

```java
Log4jContextSelector=com.example.OwnContextSelector
```

Comment: You can define system property `log4j2.messageFactory` and point to directly to your message factory to avoid implementation of the other classes.

Answer (score -1):

1) Which MessageFactory is used when I did set any?

Using @Remko Popma hint I fount out that the default message factory is `org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ParameterizedMessageFactory`.

2) Which message format uses the default factory?

The `{}` syntax which `java.util.logger` uses as well.

3) How can I set my own factory in case the default factory can't do what I need?

Don't know yet.